# Jquery-terminal Input Ctrl+D instead of calling exit method

Tags: jquery, jquery-terminal

I'm using jquery-terminal plugin to do terminal emulation in text editor.
All it does is send input to the server which inserts the input to the real 
   terminal and returns the result.

However When using Ctrl+D in jquery-terminal it calls exit()
method instead of really inserting ^D.
How can I make it send it as normal input
(would be the best if it'd work for all commands (^C, ^D, ^Z etc)

Comment: You can set keydown event as option and return false for those keys and insert ^D instead of run exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting escaped Unicode sequence (\04) did the trick